# Деплой Java проекта на heroku с подключением ClearDB MySQL (удаляются данные)

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, spring, heroku

Задеплоил проект на heroku, проверил логи, все скомпилировано без ошибок. 
Подключил ClearDB MySQL (фришный тариф), через MySQL Workbench залил данные по таблицам. Ок, приложение доступно, по всем ссылкам проходит, все данные видно.

Через час решил посмотреть все ли работает, зашел по ссылке, а данные из БД удалились, то есть все таблицы на месте, но они не заполнены.

Снова залил все данные, через час зашел, снова все удалилось. Документацию почитал, ничего поэтому поводу не нашел.

Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой? Как решили?

И что значит ограничение по коннектам = 10 (Connections - 10)?

Comment: Какое значение у параметра `ddl-auto` в конфиге приложения?

Comment: @dmtr create-drop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku останавливает приложения если они простаивают и к ним нет обращений, и стартует их, когда к ним снова появляется обращение.

Благодаря `create-drop`, хибер удаляет данные из БД при завершении приложения. При старте - создает новые таблицы.

Comment: странно, что без указания spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto приложение на heroku не запускалось. Сейчас убрал, все норм работает. Объясни, пожалуйста,в каком случае нужно использовать spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto ?

Comment: @skipperoker в том случае, когда явно хочешь указать поведение хибернейта относительно БД, ведь там различные методы поведения задаются. Не забудьте отметить ответ -_-

Comment: логично, спасибули)